# Array value can not initialize with 0 in selenium webdriver/ java

Tags: selenium

for loop value can not initialize with 0 in selenium webdriver/ java

```
String arr[] = new String[4];
for(int i = 0; i <4; i++) {
    String text = driver
        .findElement(By.xpath("html/body/select/option["+i+"]")).getText();
    arr[i] = text;
    System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
}
```

This is html which i have to read all the element.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the array with 0 but not in the scenario which you have specified.

You are finding an element with the xpath: html/body/select/option["+i+"]

where i is the position of the option element with respect to the **select** Element. It can never be zero.

If you want to start an array by zero then you should use the code specified below:

```
String arr[] = new String[4];
for(int i = 0; i <4; i++) {
    String text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/select/option")).get(i).getText();
    arr[i] = text;
    System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
}
```

**Explanation:** **driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/select/option"))** return the List of WebElement. You can get the element at index 0 which is supposed to be equivalent to "html/body/select/option[1]"

Comment: Thanks  Monika you are right, html index starts from 1

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Html indexes starts from 1, not 0. The `xpath` should be

```
"html/body/select/option["+ (i + 1) +"]"
```

However, instead of locating the option one by one you can use [Select class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/select"));
Select select = new Select(dropdown);
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
String arr[] = new String[options.size()];
for(int i = 0 ; i < options.size() ; i++) {
    arr[i] = options.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(arr[i] + " ");
}
```